# react native ios TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'ProcessingUI.Constants')

Tags: swift, react-native

The project is made using expo and then later ejected, it is working fine on android, on iOS the build is succeeded but I get this run time error: `TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'ProcessingUI.Constants')`. So, I searched a bit and maybe this error is related to `react-native-video-processing` but as I said, it is working fine on android, i.e. the app is running. Below are some details about the project and error log:

package.json:

```json
{
  "dependencies": {
    "expo": ">=44.0.0-0 <45.0.0",
    "react": "17.0.1",
    "react-devtools": "^4.24.3",
    "react-devtools-core": "^4.24.3",
    "react-dom": "17.0.1",
    "react-native": "0.64.3",
    "react-native-video-processing": "^2.0.0",
  }
}
```

Error log:

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'ProcessingUI.Constants')
at node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/ExceptionsManager.js:104:6 in reportException
at node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/ExceptionsManager.js:172:19 in handleException
at node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/setUpErrorHandling.js:24:6 in handleError
at node_modules/expo-dev-launcher/build/DevLauncherErrorManager.js:44:19 in errorHandler
at node_modules/expo-dev-launcher/build/DevLauncherErrorManager.js:49:24 in <anonymous>
at node_modules/@react-native/polyfills/error-guard.js:49:36 in ErrorUtils.reportFatalError
at node_modules/metro-runtime/src/polyfills/require.js:204:6 in guardedLoadModule
at http://192.168.29.37:8081/.vscode/exponentIndex.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false&strict=false&minify=false:547079:3 in global code
```

ADDITIONAL INFO:

The error call stack points to: `VideoPlayer.js` and when I tap on it, opens a file in `node_modules/react-native-video-processing/lib/VideoPlayer/VideoPlayer.ios.js`:

```
import { ViewPropTypes, requireNativeComponent, NativeModules, UIManager } from 'react-native';
import { getActualSource } from '../utils';
const PLAYER_COMPONENT_NAME = 'RNVideoProcessing';

const { RNVideoTrimmer } = NativeModules;

const ProcessingUI = UIManager.getViewManagerConfig('RNVideoProcessing');

export class VideoPlayer extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    source: PropTypes.oneOfType([PropTypes.string, PropTypes.number]).isRequired,
    play: PropTypes.bool,
    replay: PropTypes.bool,
    rotate: PropTypes.bool,
    currentTime: PropTypes.number,
    volume: PropTypes.number,
    startTime: PropTypes.number,
    background_Color: PropTypes.string,
    endTime: PropTypes.number,
    playerWidth: PropTypes.number,
    playerHeight: PropTypes.number,
    onChange: PropTypes.func,
    resizeMode: PropTypes.string,
    ...ViewPropTypes
  };

  static defaultProps = { // ---> error here - line 29.
    play: false,
    replay: false,
    rotate: false,
    resizeMode: ProcessingUI.Constants.ScaleNone,
    volume: 0.0,
    currentTime: 0,
    startTime: 0,
  };
  ...
```

**When I comment all the lines of code which is using `ProcessingUI` in this file, the app starts working fine in iOS**!

[image]

I am not able to resolve this issue, can someone guide me?

Thank you!

Comment: Have you completed the setup needed for `iOS`of the target npm-module?

Comment: @HendEl-Sahli yes I did, it is still the same